# Why solution 2 is much faster than the solution 1 for conditional sorting?

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem statement:**

Given a list of integers, sort it in such a manner that odd integers come before even ones 
and the integers should be in ascending order, with odd first(in ascending) then even(in ascending order)

Here is the list:

```
a = [5, 1, 4 , 6, 7,  8, 2]
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

**Solution 1:**

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: (1,x) if not x%2 else (0,x))
```

Improvised one-liner code:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: (x%2==0,x))
```

**Solution 2:**

```
sorted(sorted(a), key = lambda x:x%2==0)
```

**Update:**

```
a = np.random.randint(0,16,(2000)).tolist()
```

**Solution1:**

```
%%time
a = np.random.randint(0,16,(2000)).tolist()
a.sort(key=lambda x: (1,x) if not x%2 else (0,x))
a
```

---

```
CPU times: user 591 µs, sys: 144 µs, total: 735 µs
Wall time: 699 µs
```

**Solution1(improved):**

```
%%time
a = np.random.randint(0,16,(2000)).tolist()
a.sort(key=lambda x: (x%2==0,x))
a
```

---

```
CPU times: user 791 µs, sys: 193 µs, total: 984 µs
Wall time: 954 µs
```

**Solution2:**

```
%%time
a = np.random.randint(0,16,(2000)).tolist()
sorted(sorted(a), key = lambda x:x%2==0)
a
```

---

```
CPU times: user 351 µs, sys: 86 µs, total: 437 µs
Wall time: 409 µs
```

## Update2:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,16,(20_000)).tolist()
b = a.copy()
c = a.copy()
d = a.copy()
```

**Solution1:**

---

```
%%time
b.sort(key=lambda x: (1,x) if not x%2 else (0,x))
b
```

---

```
CPU times: user 7.62 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 7.62 ms
Wall time: 7.42 ms
```

**Solution1(improved one):**

---

```
%%time
c.sort(key=lambda x: (x%2==0,x))
c
```

---

```
CPU times: user 7.95 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 7.95 ms
Wall time: 7.47 ms
```

---

**Solution2:**

---

```
%%time
d = sorted(sorted(d), key = lambda x:x%2==0)
d
```

---

```
CPU times: user 2.71 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.71 ms
Wall time: 2.72 ms
```

Comment: First of all: How much faster, and how did you measure? Please post your benchmark code.

Comment: is it possible you ran solution 2 on `a` which was already sorted after using solution 1?

Comment: Now check I have updated the question. using %%time

Comment: Close your eyes and measure how fast you can say "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c d e f g". Then close your eyes and measure how fast you can say "1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g". Which can you do faster?

Comment: If I pass the same list to all the solution then I get this (in the update 2)